# How to __enter__ n context managers?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

Using the with statement, we can enter many context handlers using only one level of indentation/nesting:

```
>>> from contextlib import contextmanager
>>> @contextmanager
... def frobnicate(n):
...     print('frobbing {}'.format(n))
...     yield
... 
>>> frob1 = frobnicate(1)
>>> frob2 = frobnicate(2)
>>> with frob1, frob2:
...     pass
... 
frobbing 1
frobbing 2
```

But this doesn't seem to work:

```
>>> frobs = [frobnicate(1), frobnicate(2)]
>>> with *frobs:
...     pass
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can we enter *n* context managers without having to manually write out each one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python 3.3+ has [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack):

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
    contexts = [stack.enter_context(frobnicate(i)) for i in range(2)]
    ...
```

See [contextlib2](http://contextlib2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for a backport to older Python versions.